# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have implemented a `ListView` in my Android application.  I bind to this `ListView` using a custom subclass of the `ArrayAdapter` class.  Inside the overridden `ArrayAdapter.getView(...)` method, I assign an `OnClickListener`.  In the `onClick` method of the `OnClickListener`, I want to launch a new activity.  I get the exception:

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the  
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

How can I get the `Context` that the `ListView`(the current `Activity`) is working under?

Comment: I think Alex's answer should be the 'accepted' solution to your problem, since it rectifies the error you mentioned in a more generic manner

Comment: I love that "Is this really what you want?"  ... I've had a message before that said "Are you sure you didn't forget to unregister a broadcast receiver somewhere?"  AWESOME! Hats off to whoever put all these little messages in to help us squabs.

Comment: I met this issue. when I updated targetSdkVersion to 28.

Answer (score 696, accepted):

Either

- cache the Context object via constructor in your adapter, or
- get it from your view.

Or as a last resort,

- add  - FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag to your intent:

_

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Edit - i would avoid setting flags as it will interfere with normal flow of event and history stack.

Comment: What about the _autoLink_ feature of the TextView where I can not control Intent (and thus flags) created by the system?

Comment: I was getting this exception when I was doing something like this `context.startActivity(intent);` I just changed `context`from `ApplicationContext` to `Activity` type. This fixed the problem.

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk ever find a solution?

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk - autoLink will work as long as you pass the activity as context to the adapter

Comment: I passed Context object via constructor but its not work. but FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is works very well for me thanks.

Comment: getting context from view like `view.getContext()` worked for me!

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` did not work for me but using `this` did.

Comment: If you create the intent from the Application.Context, then StartActivity from the Application.Context, if you do from Activity, do both from the Activity, but never mix

Answer (score 128):

You can achieve it with **[addFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags(int))** instead of `setFlags`

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags(int)) it does:

> Add additional flags to the intent (or with existing flags value).

---

**EDIT**

Be careful  when you are using flags that you may change the history stack as [Alex Volovoy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918838/1306012) says:

> ...avoid setting flags as it will interfere with normal flow of event and history stack.

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Have you experienced any problems with the history stack or anything else as the answers above sugggest?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for but you can start an activity without a history like that:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "http:\\www.google.com"));intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
      startActivity(intent);

Comment: Why is it that not recommended to addFlags here ? How critical is it to  interfere with normal flow of event and history stack ?

Comment: @JasonKrs you can use addFlags. Just be aware that you could change the history stack depending on the flag you add. The FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK can be used in this situation. For more details read: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Answer (score 79):

Instead of using `(getApplicationContext)` use `YourActivity.this`

Comment: This worked for me i.e. using `activity.startActivity` instead of `context.startActivity`

Comment: THE BEST ANSWER!

Comment: This helped me figure out my issue.  My code ended up looking something like this: `context.currentActivity?.let { /* do things with context */ }

Comment: In Kotlin, this syntax would be `this@YourActivity` (if you are in another scope besides your activity ex. compose function)

Answer (score 66):

If you got error because of using create chooser like below:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sharingIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Open With"));
```

Set the flag to create chooser like this :

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sharingIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Open With");
chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Comment: It was very useful. Exactly chooser intent should had this flag!

Comment: This is the correct soluction, and exactly what have to do, new_task in intent.chooser

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

In addition: if you show links in listview in **fragment**, do not create it like this

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),mStrings);
```

instead call

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(),mStrings);
```

adapter works fine in both cases, but links work only in last one.

Comment: @user2676468: this solved the autolink problem for me.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, instead of using flags this is better !!

Comment: @GastónSaillén, I don't use `getApplicationContext()` (except application initialization), but caught this exception. So, situations can be different.

Comment: This was my problem, I used getApplicationContext() for context. Setting ```this``` as context works as it relates to current activity.

Answer (score 14):

I think maybe you are implementing the OnClickListener in the wrong place - usually you should definitely implement an OnItemClickListener in your Activity and set it on the ListView instead, or you will get problems with your events...

Comment: You lead me to the solution.  I needed to use an OnItemClickListener, assigned to the ListView.  Here are some links for anyone else:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example-part-2/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide generic answers. Alex Volovoy's answer below solves the problem in a generic manner.

Comment: For posterity: If you directly define it as setListener(new Listener) on a component requires a Context, you create an implicit reference to the entire activity which will leak memory like you wouldn't believe. This can be circumvented by either making a static inner class listener or by moving the listener to a separate class if it needs to be able to handle inputs from more than one origin.

Answer (score 12):

At the `Android 28(Android P)` startActivity

```
if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) == 0
        && (targetSdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.N
                || targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        && (options == null
                || ActivityOptions.fromBundle(options).getLaunchTaskId() == -1)) {
    throw new AndroidRuntimeException(
            "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity "
                    + " context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag."
                    + " Is this really what you want?");
}
```

So the best way is add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, XXXActivity.class);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is required for 28 and above devices.

Answer (score 10):

```
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter( getApplicationContext(), yourlist);
```

or

```
Context mContext = getAppliactionContext();
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter( mContext, yourlist);
```

**change to below**

```
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter( this, yourlist);
```

Answer (score 8):

See, if you are creating an intent within a listiner in some method

```
override onClick (View v).
```

then call the context through this view as well:

```
v.getContext ()
```

There will not even need SetFlags ...

Comment: And what was wrong situation? v.getApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 4):

For anybody getting this on **Xamarin.Android (MonoDroid)** even when StartActivity is called from activity - this is actually Xamarin bug with new ART runtime, see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17630

Comment: Yeah you just have to do as what's been described above, but the wording has changed...

intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(baseUrl + @"name_of_apk"));
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

Comment: NO NEED TO USE SetFlags in Xamarin.Android. Use `Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 3):

This error goes when startactivity doesn't know which is his activity. So you must add activity before startActivity()

you must set

```
context.startActivity(yourIntent);
```

Comment: If you call `startActivity` from `Fragment`, a caller can often be a fragment, not an activity.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating Alex Volovoy's answer a little more -

in case u are getting this problem with fragments, getActivity() works fine to get the context

In Other Cases:

If you don't want to use-

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//not recommend
```

then make a function like this in your OutsideClass -

```
public void gettingContext(Context context){
    real_context = context;//where real_context is a global variable of type Context
}
```

Now,in your main activity when ever you make a new OutsideClass call the above method immediately after you define the OutsideClass giving the activity's context as argument.
Also in your main activity make a function-

```
public void startNewActivity(final String activity_to_start) {
    if(activity_to_start.equals("ACTIVITY_KEY"));
    //ACTIVITY_KEY-is a custom key,just to
    //differentiate different activities
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityToStartName.class);
    activity_context.startActivity(i);      
}//you can make a if-else ladder or use switch-case
```

now come back to your OutsideClass,and to start new activity do something like this-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
........
case R.id.any_button:

            MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity) real_context;             
            mainAct.startNewActivity("ACTIVITY_KEY");                   

        break;
    }
........
}
```

This way you will be able to start different activities called from different OutsideClass without messing up with flags.

Note-Try not to cache context object via constructor for fragment(with adapter,its fine).A fragment should have a empty constructor otherwise application crashes in some scenarios.

remember to call

```
OutsideClass.gettingContext(Context context);
```

in the onResume() function as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it's better to use the method of `startActivity()` just in the your code of the `Activity.class`.  If you use that in the `Adapter` or other class, it will result in that.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. Check all the context that you have passed. For '**links**' it needs **Activity Context** not **Application context**.

This are the place where you should check :

1.) If you used **LayoutInflater** then check what context you have passed.

2.) If you are using any **Adapter** check what context you have passed.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in your Adapter_Activity and use `context.startActivity(intent_Object)` and `intent_Object.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Like this:

```
Intent n_act = new Intent(context, N_Activity.class);
n_act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(n_act);
```

It Works....

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity (where you're calling the adapter) just change `getActivityContext()` with `YourActivity.this`.
Here's an exemple:

```
yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(yourList, YourActivity.this); // Here YourActivity.this is the Context instead of getActivityContext()
recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);    
viewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

i hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue then implemented

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and got solved the problem.

There may be an another reason which is related to list view adapter.
You can see [This blog](http://androidbreakdown.blogspot.in/2017/06/FLAGACTIVITYNEWTASK.html), described it very well.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Works fine for me. Share Something from Outside of an activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");

// Append Text
String Text = "Your Text Here"

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Text);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share . . . ");
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
G.context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: Setting up flags mess up stacktrace history

Answer (score 1):

Since adding flags affect `event_flow` and `stack_history` it is better to pass the 'application context' to the non-activity from where you need to call an activity class in the following way:

"ActivityClassName.this" (While you pass the context in this manner it will contain all the detail and info that you need to call an Activity from a non-activity scenario)

So there is no need to set or add flags, this will work fine in every case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use databinding, just get your context with

```
binding.root.context
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i= new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are invoking share Intent in Cordova plugin, setting the Flag will not help. Instead use this -

```
cordova.getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "title"));
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation was a little different, I'm testing my app using `Espresso` and I had to launch my Activity with `ActivityTestRule` from the instrumentation `Context` (which is not the one coming from an `Activity`).

```
fun intent(context: Context) = 
    Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
```

I had to change the flags and add an `or` bitwise ( `|` in Java) with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

So it results in:

```
fun intent(context: Context) = 
    Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin version

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
this.startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context get from your view**

> Don't

```
val context = activity.applicationContext
openBrowser(context, MenuUrl.TERM_CONDITION)
```

> Do

```
   1. val context = binding.root.context // If you are using view binding
   2. val context = yourView.context // If you are not use view binding
    openBrowser(context, MenuUrl.TERM_CONDITION)
```

*Thank You.*

Answer (score 0):

For people coming from **Xamarin.Forms** or **Xamarin.Android**, In your Xamarin.Android project, use:

```cs
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(intent);
```

**Note** that this might require Xamarin.Essentials v1.5 or above

As @Alex Volovoy mentioned, setting flags should be avoided as it will interfere with normal flow of event and history stack.

Answer (score 0):

**If You are Using Chrome Custom Tab Then**

```
 if (ctx.isPackageInstalled("com.android.chrome")) {
        customBuilder.apply {
            intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome")
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) //Add This Flag
            launchUrl(ctx, Uri.parse(URL))
        }

    }
```