# setting autolink property

Tags: android, android-layout

i have some urls in array when i click on the text view it need to open the page but im getting error my code is

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
    l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    String[] textArray={"www.google.co.in","www.gmail.com","www.facebook.com"};
    int length=textArray.length;
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    setContentView(layout);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);        
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setText(textArray[i]);
        layout.addView(tv);
       Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
       tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
```

> LogCat output

```
12-20 16:08:38.623: E/InputEventReceiver(2170): Exception dispatching input event.
12-20 16:08:38.623: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:944)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7397)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-20 16:08:38.804: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 16:08:38.804: D/AndroidRuntime(2170): Shutting down VM
12-20 16:08:38.813: W/dalvikvm(2170): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:944)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7397)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-20 16:08:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: looks like you're not in an activity, you have to use the NEW_TASK flag. Also, please reformat your logcat, that's quite hard to read

Answer (score 2):

In addition: if you show links in adapter in fragment, do not create it like this

```
    adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),mStrings,dispWidth,dispHeight);
```

instead call

```
    adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(),mStrings,dispWidth,dispHeight);
```

adapter works fine in both cases, but links work only in last one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I suppose you should use WebView for opening any Links.You can get an idea from here with a Simple Example of How to Handle a WebView.The Link is as follows:-[WebView Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/).
I hope this helps you a lot.

I feel that in your Logcat your problem's solution can be fulfilled by the following link:-[Your Logcat Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are starting an `Activity` from out side the context of `Activity`

simple short answer in you code where you start an activity make sure that the context that start it is an an `Activity` otherwise make sure to set the Intent Flag to `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
..
...
..

mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's not an Intent. It's an "autolink" in one of the Recycler items. Since there's no actual code launching the link this can be problematic. I haven't solved this myself...

Answer (score 0):

Check Nammari´s response or if have that code inside a getView() method to avoid that exception

> "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

probably you need :

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(parent.getContext());
...
...
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(parent.getContext());
```

instead of

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
...
...
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);` to `LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(getParent.getApplicationContext());`