# Start activity from adapter don't work with SwipeListView library

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-adapter

I'm using [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) library and I'm getting error when trying to start an activity in my adapter.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

private Context context;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Product> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    final Product product = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cproduct_list_item, null);

        viewHolder.nom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.commerce = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commerce);
        viewHolder.prix = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        viewHolder.bAction1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.example_row_b_action_1);
        viewHolder.bAction2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.example_row_b_action_2);
        viewHolder.bAction3 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.example_row_b_action_3);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } 
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.nom.setText(product.getName());
    viewHolder.commerce.setText(product.getCommerce());
    viewHolder.prix.setText(String.format("%s F", product.getPrice()));

    viewHolder.bAction1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView nom;
    TextView commerce;
    TextView prix;
    Button bAction1;
    Button bAction2;
    Button bAction3;
}
}
```

When I click on the button I get this error: "The application has stopped unexpectedly". But when I use a Toast, it works fine. I think there is something inconsistent with starting activity.

Logcat:

> 04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at com.tomsyweb.suna.ProductAdapter$2.onClick(ProductAdapter.java:71)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>   04-16 18:42:29.531: E/AndroidRuntime(29813):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` is a field of `ProductAdapter` in your case and you don't initialize it with any value, so it's `null`. Use `getContext()` instead or initialize `context` field with `this.context = context`.

Comment: getContext() doesn't solve the problem. I get another log error: 04-16 19:20:32.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32041): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
04-16 19:20:32.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32041):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:654)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally get a solution here (use myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context

Comment: It's not a good idea really. If the context you pass to the `ProductAdapter` is an `Activity`, you'd better save it in a field and use to start another `Activity` without creating a new task.

Comment: Don't exactly understand what you say. Can you illustrate it with some piece of code?

Comment: Save the `context` you pass to the `ProductAdapter` in a field: `this.context = context;`. Then use this field to start an `Activity`, like you did in the question.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work: "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag"

Comment: What do you pass as a `context` to `ProductAdapter`?

Comment: Context context;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Product> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects); this.context = context;
}

Comment: No, I mean when you create a `ProductAdapter` with `new ProductAdapter(...)` what is the first argument there?

Comment: Oh, never use it! I think you call it from an `Activity` subclass, so just pass this activity to the constructor (`this` in your case). Then you can remove the `context` field from the `ProductAdapter` class and  use `getContext()` without any limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the `Context` in the constructor, so you can store into the variable context:

```
private Context context;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Product> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context; //*** Here!
}
```

And use it into your `Adapter` class, for example:

```
...
...
  viewHolder.bAction1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
...
...
```