# Cannot start activity from non-activity class

Tags: android

OK this question has been asked many times in the past and I went through a lot of them but I still couldn't figure out what is the right way of doing this.

In my app I have a login activity. I am making some api hits inside a thread inside a class (Lets call it ApiHitter) that implements runnable. If any of these api hit returns an error I want to logout the user (might sound weird, but for some reasons I need this functionality)

Now what i have done uptill now is that inside my non-activity class (ApiHitter) I created an init fuction to get Context like this.

```
public static void init(Context applicationContext) {

        appContext = applicationContext;

    }
```

I pass context to this class at my splash activity by calling ApiHitter.init(context). Whenever I needed a context in this class this approach worked fine. But it doesn't help me to start the login activity. I tried to call init from LoginActivity as well but that doesn't work either. This is how I try to start the activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
(appContext).startActivity(intent);
```

I also tried setFlags instead of addFlags but in vain.

I am not getting any error but can't start LoginActivity.

Since I am already setting the flag I assume that context is the culprit. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Can't you simply use `Context appContext = getApplicationContext();`?

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); did u try this ?

Comment: You aren't using the suggested `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context)

Comment: @EdGeorge, Sameer, I tried that, it doesn't cause any errors but I can't change the activity either.