# android adapter Onclick open new activty

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using this code for make new listener for every new item

first the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
android:padding="8dp"
android:id="@+id/showonmap"
android:alpha="0.9">

<!-- Thumbnail Image -->

<!-- notofocation  Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!--   -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

<!-- Genre -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/genre"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rating"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/genre"
    android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />

<!-- date -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="@color/year"
    android:textSize="@dimen/year" />
```

I just parse the JSON array response and make new item depend on array length

after that I add listener to the

> ..  RelativeLayout with id showonmap

and when click on its it open new activity 
the code of Onclick

```
showonmaps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, show_notification.class);
            intent.putExtra("lat", m.getGenre().get(0));
            intent.putExtra("lang", m.getGenre().get(1));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


            context.startActivity(intent);





        }
    });
```

here I am using

```
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

and when use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                            show_notification.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
```

the application stopped so i must back and use

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

but when I use it and open new activity and press back button its exit from the application any idea or solution ?

Comment: you can call onBackPressed() with previous Activity

Comment: Remove this line: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`. When setting this flag you are basically starting a new activity stack. I see that your applicaiton crashed when removing, so you are probably using a context which is not allowed to launch an Activity i.e. an application context (`getApplicationContext()`)

Comment: use this  yourActivity.this instead of context like,Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this,
                            show_notification.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

Comment: @PradeepGupta its not activity its a class
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter and i just pass the context when construct the class

Comment: ok, will you please add your  code of adapter

Comment: ok just a moment i will edit it

Comment: it would be better to know why the application stopped when clicked on back button, attach a log section of the crash

Comment: @visionixvisionix its give me this
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context

Comment: what context you send to the adapter of the listview?

Comment: getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i slove it by pass the activity and context to the class

the code will be

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, show_notification.class);
activity.startActivity(yourIntent);
```

context and  activity thats what you pass it when construct the class

and this question was helped me to find the sloution

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context)