# Send an email +attachment using dependency services DROID Xamarin forms

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, dependencies, email-attachments

I came across this error when Trying to send an email with attachment. any help ? Thank you

****Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?****

this is my code :

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(sendEmail))]
namespace myapp.Droid
{
    public class sendEmail : IEmailTask
    {
        public sendEmail()
        {

        }

        public void SendEmail () 
        {
            var sqlliteFilname = "test.3gpp";
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var stringPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqlliteFilname);

            var path = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new 
           Java.IO.File(stringPath));

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
            // set the type to 'email'
            emailIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("mailto:"));

            String[] to = { "youremail@mail.com" };

            emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, to);
            // the attachment
            emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, path);
            // the mail subject
            emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Subject");

           Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));


        }
    }
}
```

code on the page is :

```
 void btnSendingHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var getEmail = DependencyService.Get<IEmailTask>();

            getEmail.SendEmail();
        }
```

Comment: Since this is a Forms app I'd try changing your Context to  `Forms.Context.StartActivity (Intent.CreateChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you have an attachment to send.
*To be replace for the if block & change this

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
//change it to 


Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendto);
```

*Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));*

```
if (emailIntent.ResolveActivity(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager) != null)
            {
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(emailIntent);
            }
            else
            {

                    string tag = "MY-EMAIL";
                    Log.Info(tag, "no attachment found");
            }
```

my issue relies on the attachment itself.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nick had said

- you could use `Forms.Context` to start activity.

Or

- you could add `emailIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);` in your `emailIntent.`

> In Android, every `Activity` should have its own task stack which you can use [taskAffinity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) to define it, the package's name is the default value. But if you use `Application.Context` to start activity, there is not task stack for your activity, so it suggests you to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, this flag will create a task stack for you activity.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried both solutions , but I am still getting the same error . I dont get the option to add Forms.context ,  Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));

Comment: where exactly should I call this task ?  emailIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

Comment: Not `Forms.context`, it is `Forms.Context`, make sure it is  `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context`, and [this is the document about task stack in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html), [this is about the error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context)