# Cannot resolve method (android.content.intent)

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new to Android development and I am having the following project structure:

[image]

I would like to start my `activity_category_list` from the `StoreViewHolder` class of mine. That is, whenever a view is in the holder is clicked, category activity should start.

Here is my **StoreViewHolder.java** to achieve this:

```
public class StoreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView txtStoreName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public StoreViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtStoreName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.store_image);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), false);
        Intent categoryList = new Intent(view.getContext(), CategoryList.class);
        this.startActivity(categoryList); // does not compile here
    }
}
```

I get the titled error on the commented section. I tried various methods I have seen online but somehow none worked. Alternatively I also tried this but no luck:

```
 Intent categoryList = new Intent(StoreViewHolder.this, CategoryList.class);
 startActivity(categoryList);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call `startActivity(intent)` you need `context`. Because `startActivity(intent)` method comes from [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) class. In `Activity`  you don't write like `context.startActivity(intent);` because `Activity` it self a `Context` as `Acitivty` extends `Context`.  Pass `Context` in constructor and call `context.startActivity(intent);`

```
public class StoreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView txtStoreName;
public ImageView imageView;
Context context;

private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public StoreViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context = context;
    txtStoreName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.store_image);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    itemClickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), false);
    Intent categoryList = new Intent(view.getContext(), CategoryList.class);
    context.startActivity(categoryList); // does not compile here
}
}
```

Similar question [Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context)

Comment: That leads to a crash with the log of  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference`

Comment: did you create `StoreViewHolder` with `View` and `Context`  with constructor `StoreViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) ` ?

Comment: @Sch then your Context is wrong when you made `new StoreViewHolder`

Comment: By the way, `view.getContext()` should probably be used instead

Comment: yes `view.getContext()` can also be used.

Comment: Yes @AbuYousuf that was the problem. Thanks a lot.