# How to navigate to a Xamarin.Android module activity from a Xamarin.forms Page? How to achieve the same in Xamarin.iOS as well?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

am relatively new to Xamarin. I have a solution with Xamarin.Forms project and a Xamarin.Android(Native) project. Is it possible to launch the Activity in the Native module from a 'Page' in Xamarin.forms, say when we click on a button. Also is the same applicable in Xamarin.iOS ?

Comment: To be honest NO!

Comment: @G.hakim, why no?

Comment: You want an Android code to work in xamarin forms for ios right? or maybe I'm not getting you, your question looks ambiguous

Comment: To clarify I have xamarin.android module and xamarin.ios module as well. And am trying to access these in the specific platform from the xamarin.forms module.

Comment: @JoeLvMSFT Trying out the solution seen in the picture. What happened to me was that I had already created modules in Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS (ie. native projects). Later I decided to add a Xamarin forms project as the launch module. Hence ending up with App,App.Droid and App.iOS and additionally App2.Droid and App2.iOS modules.

Comment: @JoeLvMSFT right now am trying to replace the App.Droid and App.iOS modules with App2.Droid and App2.iOS. Any suggestions.

Comment: @MidhunKumar, I am not sure what about `App.Droid and App.iOS modules`, why not create a Xamarin.forms project directly? Or can you give me a picture about your project?

Comment: If I am right, you don't have the PCL which I mentioned in my answer, and now you want to add it? You can create a `Cross-Platform`->`Class Library`, in your solution, and then reference it in your Android and Ios project.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to launch the Activity in the Native module from a 'Page' in Xamarin.forms, say when we click on a button

The answer is yes.

---

You can use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to achieve it.

In Android:

1) Define a interface in PCL:

```
public interface IOpenPage
{
    void OpenPage();
}
```

2) Implement the interface in Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenPageImpl))]
namespace App2.Droid
{
    class OpenPageImpl : IOpenPage
    {   

        public void OpenPage()
        {
            Forms.Context.StartActivity(new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(TextActivity)));
        }
    }
}
```

3) In your button's click event:

```
private void ToPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IOpenPage>().OpenPage();
}
```

## Update:

Xamarin.forms project:

[image]

Comment: So I need to define the interface in the android module which is part of the xamarin.forms project . And implement the interface inside the xamarin.android module?

Comment: By `android module`, what do you mean? Your  `xamarin.forms module` is my PCL.

Comment: No, you need define the interface in xamarin.forms module. And inplement the interface inside the xamarin.android module.

Comment: So it will be implemented in the Xamarin.Android Project, the native one, which was not generated as part of the Xamarin Forms project?

Comment: Please look the picture.

Comment: But Forms.Context is obsolete now. Is there any workaround for that.

Comment: Try this `Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(TextActivity)));`

Comment: I was able to implement the delegate and open the forms page in iOS as well but not sure about how to open another view controller from this page. ie how we will use this IOpenPage interface here.

Comment: Any idea about how to achieve the same in iOS, ie how to push a view controller into the scene from Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Also, the android implementation works sometimes and crashes sometimes. Observed the error message: Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? xamarin forms

Comment: @MidhunKumar `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK `, you need add a flag, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context), because you are using Application Context, so there is no stack for it.

Comment: @MidhunKumar About Ios, sorry, I am not familiar with Ios, but I think the idea is the same. You can open an new thread with Xamarin.Ios tag.

Comment: so while navigating from forms to native through dependency service do we have to add this flag?

Comment: If you can get MainActivity's Context, you don't need it, I haven't tried it, and I don't think I can get it, so I usually use the Application's Context. Every Activity must have [taskAffinity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html?#aff).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167143/discussion-between-midhun-kumar-and-joe-lv-msft).