# android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick

**check below my code,. this code is in my adapter. but the thing is my phone is totally supported app and shared but the lower version mobile not supported its forced to closed when click on share.**

```
 share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String shareBody = "\t\t DIL KI BAAT \n\n" +sayari[position].toString().trim()+"\n\n\n"+ "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                    + appPackageName;

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, context.getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.app_name)));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context)

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: **my error is this**   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @sasikumar but letest phone already work in this code , not work in lower version of small android phone ?

Comment: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag` you didn't try to search this error message in google, did you?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i have already try it but google give me same answer you add  **addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);** and i add this line in my cod e bt not working

Comment: You added that flag to wrong intent

Answer (score 4):

You need to add this flag not for the sharing intent, but for intent you are starting activity with:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

Intent startIntent = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(startIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this before calling startActivity

`sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` .If you don't use the activity context this is required.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get out of this issue is to start activity from adapters parent activity. Either use context object or use an Interface, pass them as parameter to adapter's constructor. Invoke a method in your activity using passed reference. Here is an example:

Create an interface:

```
public interface ActivityInteractor{
    public void showDetails();
}
```

Let your Activity imlement it:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ActivityInteractor{
    public void showDetails(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Then pass your activity to ListAdater:

public MyAdapter extends BaseAdater{
    private ActivityInteractor listener;

```
public MyAdapter(ActivityInteractor listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

}
And somewhere in adapter, when you need to call that Activity method:

```
listener.showDetails();
```

Comment: Done, and Thanks