# How can I link from my app to Android Accessibility Font Size settings?

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent

In my React Native mobile app, I want to link from my app's settings to the Android Settings > Accessibility > Font Size view so that a user can quickly adjust text size.

At first I tried using the [react native Linking API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking). I had no luck. Specifically, I tried to use `Linking.sendIntent` but it just complained about missing an activity new task flag.

Next, I did some research and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59349273/605688) which suggests that it's not possible (which seems weird but I didn't read the source code) and to use the [react-native-send-intent](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent) library.

After installing the library, I can do something like this:

```
if (Platform.OS === "android") {
  SendIntentAndroid.openSettings("android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS");
}
```

This successfully takes me to the Accessibility Settings, however, I want to link specifically to the "Font Size" view within Accessibility settings.

Searching in [the android docs for Settings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html), I don't see any specific intent for this. Is this possible? How do I do this?

I am using React Native version 0.63.4 if that matters.