# Opening Google Play Store from my Application class

Tags: java, android

I have implemented the following after seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/5550161) answer:

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

But I get the following crash:

```
AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
```

The log gives me the reason for the crash, but I'm not sure if I'm implementing it correctly since I can't test it (I was unable to reproduce the issue).

So I changed the above to the following:

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
```

**Please note** this is being called inside my Application class.

---

Can someone please confirm if I'm doing it correctly? As I have mentioned, I can't test if the issue is resolved.

**EDIT 1:**

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918838/11951642) answer, I'm not sure if setting the flag is the correct approach?

Comment: `confirm if I'm doing it correctly` looks like you are, but why `I can't test`?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko The crash comes from crashlytics.

Comment: it should crash on any device, not only some specific

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you for your reply, I will test again to see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: FYI: in your case adding flag is fine, and should not infloence activity stack as you are starting another application's activity with that flag.

Comment: hi can you confirm the OS version code for device. since there are some issues related to starting activity from outside of the activity context without adding necessary flags. most probably it happens in marshamallow i guess.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thank you, I was able to reproduce the crash and adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` fixed it.

Comment: Why are you calling this from Application class ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried starting your intent in the reference of your context? like:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

I was having same issue and that helped me, Also you may use `getApplicationContext();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't set `context.startActivity` because I'm calling it from my Application class, as mentioned in the question. I have resolved the issue.

Comment: Okay, Nice then!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your passing wrong package name that's why this AndroidRuntimeException exception occurs. I'm facing this issue and below code resolved my problem.

Check my below code which I have used in my code.

```
try {
       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)));
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)));
}
finish();
```